# Минифицировать html разметку в Laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel, минификация

подскажите как можно минифицировать html разметку в Laravel.
Пользовательские шаблоны идут как blade. шаблоны, админская часть на  Vue.js. Но главный вопрос как можно минифицировать именно пользовательскую часть, которая построена на blade ? Видел несколько библиотек, которые нужно подгружать через composer, но так как я работаю по win10 системой, настройки компосера ругаются на установку зависимостей.
Товарищ подсказывал, что из коробки Laravel должен минифицировать blade шаблоны через Node.js, так ли я его понял ? Если это так, то мне нужно будет правильно выполнить npm install на OpenServer localhost, с настройками под windows, чтобы Node своими силами сам ужал html разметку.

Comment: На что именно ругается композер? Тоже сижу под виндой и ещё ни разу не было ошибок которые возникают только на винде... И для чего минифицировать html? Какой от этого профит?

Comment: Ускорение загрузки сайта. А ругается на ошибки типа:
audited 1047 packages in 4.943s
found 5 vulnerabilities (1 low, 4 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: это не ругань, а отчёт об используемых пакетах node.js, но никак не ругань. ничто не мешает вам использовать именно тот набор пакетов, который у вас используется в данный момент

Comment: Да, уже осознал это и обновил пакеты. Это не критично, а вот что было дальше.
Гуглил как минифицировать html файлы для моего Laravel 5.6. И вот что мне выдает поисковик: https://github.com/HTMLMin/Laravel-HTMLMin
Для установки библиотечки нужно сделать composer require htmlmin/htmlmin
Но вот уже выдате ошибки вида:
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Comment: Стоит ли задумка выделки? Вначале попробуйте изменить размеры всего остального и посмотрите, попробовал на сайте, html до минификации 823кб после 784кб(39кб, 4%), а если вообще все пробелы, табы и переносы(во всём тексте) убрать 701... Профит в 122кб если смотреть в процентах то 14.8... Но если смотреть размеры и скорость интернета то вообще ни о чём... Практически не встречаю минифицированного html, даже если смотреть на СО